# Как выровнять grid-блок по ширине размера окна?

Tags: html, css3, html5, css-grid

У меня есть 8 элементов расположеных в два ряда по горизонтали.
Для позиционирования, я использовал CSS Grid Layout.
Далее после верстки основной станицы, я начал её адаптировать, но появился горизонтальный скролл, блоки остались такой же шириной что и были.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы блоки выравнивались, растягивались по ширине экрана при любом разрешении?

[image: Основное разрешение]

[image: Разрешение при 1100px]

HTML-код блока

```css
    .grid-element-one {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #F7F0DD;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.grid-element-two {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #F7F0DD;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.grid-element-three {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #F7F0DD;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.grid-element-four {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #F7F0DD;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.grid-element-one:hover {
    background-color: #ffec41;
    transition: 900ms;
}
.grid-element-two:hover {
    background-color: #FF2929;
    transition: 900ms;
}
.grid-element-three:hover {
    background-color: #4f75f4;
    transition: 900ms;
}
.grid-element-four:hover {
    background-color: #49cc63;
    transition: 900ms;
}
.block__products-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "a b c d"
                         "f g e h";
    grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
HTML-код блока

<div class="block__products-grid wrap">
    <div class="grid-element-one"></div>
    <div class="grid-element-two"></div>
    <div class="grid-element-three"></div>
    <div class="grid-element-four"></div>
    <div class="grid-element-one"></div>
    <div class="grid-element-two"></div>
    <div class="grid-element-three"></div>
    <div class="grid-element-four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая конструкция в grid: auto-fit + minmax(). Она позволяет создавать отзывчивую раскладку без медиа-запросов:

```css
.block__products-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
}
.grid-element {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #F7F0DD;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .9s;
}
.grid-element-one:hover {
    background-color: #ffec41;
}
.grid-element-two:hover {
    background-color: #FF2929;
}
.grid-element-three:hover {
    background-color: #4f75f4;
}
.grid-element-four:hover {
    background-color: #49cc63;
}
```

```html
<div class="block__products-grid wrap">
    <div class="grid-element grid-element-one"></div>
    <div class="grid-element grid-element-two"></div>
    <div class="grid-element grid-element-three"></div>
    <div class="grid-element grid-element-four"></div>
    <div class="grid-element grid-element-one"></div>
    <div class="grid-element grid-element-two"></div>
    <div class="grid-element grid-element-three"></div>
    <div class="grid-element grid-element-four"></div>
</div>
```